# SDL GUI Library?

Tags: c++, user-interface, sdl

Anyone know of a good SDL GUI library that has standard widgets?  There are tons of them that turn up in google, but majority of them look like they came straight out of 1992.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard widgets"?  Screenshots or mockups might help.

Comment: Scroll bars, text boxes, buttons, progress bars, etc.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to tell what you are looking for but I would probably look at
http://libagar.org/